# Is giving an element an extra attribute going to make the page load faster than giving that element a child element instead?

Tags: html

I ask this because I need to make my anchor tags accessible and I can either give them a title attribute or give them an invisible span tag with content.

Comment: The difference is a few byte. It doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @JohannesH. any small difference can add up to a lot when you have numerous tags

Comment: No, it won't really add up to a significant number, unless we're talking about thousands of entries. And even then, overall loading time will be way bigger than the small difference

Comment: You sort of answered your own question in your comment.  It really depends on the size of the child element/node.  A child element can be long/big and if used multiple times it will increase the size of the document, hence affect load times - attributes, in turn, will tend to be smaller.  At this point, I would be concerned about requirements instead of performance

Comment: In terms of bytes, even one image will run circles around your extra attributes. It terms of DOM-rendering I don't know but it's probably insignificant as well.

Comment: In Terms of DOM rendering, a child element is one node, and an attribute is one node as well. SHouldn't matter.